# How am I supposed to test if an assembly procedure works?

Tags: testing, assembly, procedure, x86-16

I'm starting to learn assembly.

Let's say I write a procedure to find to minium value in an array of integers.

```
PUBLIC _findmin
.MODEL SMALL
.CODE
_findmin PROC

   // code here...

_findmin ENDP
END
```

How can I test if it does actually work?
How can I execute this code?

Comment: By assembling and linking the code, and running the resulting executable.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of confirming your code is working. One is to go through a debugger. If you are testing against multiple resulty, you can also write a simple wrapper and loop with various input parameters, comparing the output to the expected result. I did this when I wrote a kind of pattern matching algorithm, because it's hard to keep track of all possible patterns and making sure they still work after a change.

There are also testframworks for more complex code.